# Array modifier and rotating around geometric object (decagon)

Tags: modifiers, geometry, mathematics

I have a decagon that I'm trying to place 20 upside down "**U**" shape dividers around it using the array modifier but every other "U" shape is not matching up.  How can I fix this so that they line up.

Here's an image of them lined up correctly circled in **green**.

[image: img1]

Here's an image of them not lined up correctly in **red**

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

I've also included the blend file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that your U shaped objects are being offset.  Add a circle and set its vertex count to 20 in the Last Operator Adjust panel.  Something around 41.4mm radius will have the circle vertices just touch the edges of the U shapes in the array:

[image: circle just touching the U shapes]

Your problem is that the flat parts of the cylinder aren't the same distance from the center as the corners, as you can see by adjusting the radius of the circle to around 43.4mm:

[image: circle touching the flats but not corners]

The easiest solution would probably be to use two Bezier curves adjusted to the proper radii, and have two separate U objects, each with 10 elements in its array, although you could make your approach work as well.